# Oracle Number Rouding Issue

Tags: oracle, rounding

We need to **Round Half-UP** the following NUMBER:

```
28.854623
```

So, the 'expected' steps are:

```
1) 28.854623
2) 28.85462
3) 28.8546
4) 28.855
5) 28.86
```

But, the result from the ROUND function appears to be wrong:

```
SELECT ROUND(28.854623, 2) FROM DUAL;
Result> 28.85
```

If we execute with 3 decimals places, the result is as expected:

```
SELECT ROUND(28.854623, 3) FROM DUAL;
Result> 28.855
```

If we ROUND to 3 places, and then to 2 places, the results are also the expected:

```
SELECT ROUND (ROUND (28.854623, 3), 2) FROM DUAL
Result> 28.86
```

Could anybody explains me why this behavior? Isn't the ROUND function making a TRUNC on the (N+1) Decimal place and then, Round the result, something like this:

```
ROUND(TRUNC(VALUE, N+1), N)
```

Thanks!

Comment: [The documentation explains the algorithm used](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions155.htm). It's doing what it is supposed to do. Are you really sure you want/need to use an unconventional approach?

Comment: Why is this tagged Java and BigDecimal? I've removed those tags - if they are important to you then please edit them back in (and explain why).

Comment: Normally the purpose of rounding is to reduce the number of digits of precision, while *minimising* the overall error introduced. Your method of iterative rounding would introduce a greater overall error for no benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No rounding function I've ever seen will start at the last decimal and work backwards like that. Round functions will look 1 character past your required decimal count (<strike>possibly 1 character further if the first it find is a 5</strike> MT0 clarified that if the next character is a 5, Oracle rounds away from 0 ).

In your example, `ROUND(28.854623, 2)` would look at `28.854` and say 'round down'. Behavior is as I would expect.

If you want a function to round like you described, you'd likely need to implement one yourself.

Comment: If you are rounding to `N` decimal places and the `N+1`th is a 5 then `ROUND()` will always round away from zero. You do not need to look beyond the next decimal place.

Comment: Hello @Tyler. I always figured the ROUND function (both Oracle and in Java) worked considering all significant decimal places, as we learned in school. His explanation clarified and showed that this approach does not make much sense. Thank you for help.

Comment: @MT0 Good to know. I wasn't sure if it followed round up or round even. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @regisxp Java will also round as I described.

Answer (score 2):

@Tyler has described how `ROUND()` works and the algorithm is detailed in the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions155.htm#SQLRF00698).

> ROUND is implemented using the following rules:
>
> 1. If n is 0, then ROUND always returns 0 regardless of integer.
> 2. If n is negative, then ROUND(n, integer) returns -ROUND(-n, integer).
> 3. If n is positive, then `ROUND(n, integer) = FLOOR(n * POWER(10, integer) + 0.5) * POWER(10, -integer)`

If you really want to round as you describe then you can create your own function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION round_strangely(
  value  IN NUMBER,
  places IN INT DEFAULT 0
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
AS
  shifted NUMBER      := ABS( value ) * POWER( 10, places );
BEGIN
  RETURN ( FLOOR( shifted )
           + CASE WHEN 9 * MOD( shifted, 1 ) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         )
         * SIGN( value )
         / POWER( 10, places );
END;
/
```

Which can be used as per `ROUND()`:

```
WITH numbers ( value, dp ) AS (
SELECT 28.854623, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 28.854623, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 28.854623, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 28.854623, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 28.852623, 1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT value,
       ROUND_STRANGELY( value, dp ) AS rounded
FROM   numbers;
```

and gives the output:

```
     VALUE    ROUNDED
---------- ----------
 28.854623   28.85462 
 28.854623    28.8546 
 28.854623     28.855 
 28.854623      28.86 
 28.852623       28.9
```

But what your algorithm is doing is not rounding half-up but it is rounding above-four-ninths-up (since .4 recurring would round down but .444...445 would round up).

Comment: Hello @MT0. Thanks a lot for providing an example of how could we achieve the desired results. It was inspiring.